# How do i convert this from horizontal to vertical in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to change this horizontal format table

[image: Horizontal Format]

to like this format (vertically based) where the dates are vertical

[image: Vertical]

and the part number will duplicated for the dates

I tried of recording macros or using transpose special.
But since the first column has to duplicate as the dates go, i wasnt able to.

Will really appreciate the help! Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Power Query** it is an add-in that you can download and install easily, in Excel 2016 is a default in **Data** tab:

1. Go to **Power Query** tab or **Data** Tab and select **From Table/Range**. **OK**.

It will open the Query Editor, there:

2. With <kbd>CTRL</kbd> select [Product Line] to [MPA] field.
3. Go to **Transform** tab and look for **Unpivot Columns**.
4. Select **Unpivot Other Columns**.
5. Go to **Close and Load** in **Home** tab.

It will create a new table with your data transformed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the gif demo! But when i tried clicking the "From Table/Range" option, my excel crashes

Comment: Can you show me the error? You can use first **Format as Table** in **Home** tab. Then try again **From Table/Range**.

Comment: It does not give me an error message box but the excel window just closes when i click on "from table"

Comment: Mmm it is a malfunction. Which Excel version do you have?

Comment: mine is office 2016

Comment: All what I am reading about that say that it is an installation issue or a conflict with malware antivirus. The solutions I found are repair or reinstall again Excel unfortunately :/

Comment: After much uninstalling and restarting, it works. But the above method doesnt work for pivot table?

Comment: No it doesn't. Power Query is for transform data before analysis. You can create a pivot table on base of that transformation. It is great because you can connect multiple sources and transform them as you need it without using VBA.

Comment: I did it with the original data source and it worked well. Thks. And if i were to  re upload a new set of data, and i record this as macro and run, it wouldnt work right. Is there any alternatives then? Or is it only possible through VBA then? Thks

Comment: You don't need VBA. PQ creates a second table with the data transformed. If you look inside the Query Editor you will see in the right box each steep that you made. In this way if you add more data to the main table or a new set of data it will be just a right click **Refresh**, it will repeat each steep and transform the data into the new table and that's it. This as long you don't change the structure I mean you don't delete or change names in the fields it will work. Try to connect direct your source to Power Query.

Comment: ...Inside it has a **Power M Code** that you can see in **Advanced Editor** in **Home** tab. There you can edit line by line the transformation as you want.  I would recommend you if you are into Data Analysis and Microsoft put an eye in **Power Pivot**, **Power Query** or **Get & Transform**, **Power View** < **Power BI**. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZCO3y27z8E

Comment: Please don't forget mark my answer as the answer in your post I am building my reputation :)

Comment: Sorry. new here! Thanks for ur quick reply and suggestions! :)